# Page starting out too wide when when they load

Tags: css, wordpress

This has been driving me nuts. It's a Wordpress site but I feel it's CSS related since it happens with both gallery plugins I have tried.  I've tried both Go Portfolio and RoboGallery. But I always end up with the same results.

The galleries are set to a percentage of the width to be responsive.

For some reason when the page initially loads the galleries load and are spread out beyond the width of the page. As soon as I adjust something on the page, either the width or I click the gallery filter then it resets and looks good. But until I do that, the gallery looks like crap.

Here are 2 links to pages where this is happing. One is Go Portfolio, the other is RoboGallery.

http://www.glossyfinish.com/portolio/action-photos/

http://www.glossyfinish.com/test-pano/

Comment: I've tried adding an overflow: hidden. But it just hides the content that doesn't fit until I adjust the page width.

Comment: My best guess would be that the code that inits the galleries is called while the gallery container width is still being calculated. Try creating the gallery after the page is loaded, or perhaps, try triggering resize event manually: `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow-x:hidden` property in body

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: It was able to cut the edges off but the grid view was still skewed.

Comment: Some of your logo have 1200px width. Set `max-width: 100%` to your logo or even for all image on your website
`.header-logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}`

Comment: Taras!!!  Thank you.  that was it.  This has been driving me crazy for weeks. Thank you!